# How to accept JsonArray as input to WebAPI

Tags: asp.net-core, json.net, asp.net-core-webapi, system.text.json

I am using .Net 6 WebAPI. I need to accept a generic JSON array as input. The properties present in each JSON document is not known before. So I cannot Deserialize to specific object type. So I am looking for 2 inputs.
a) What should be input datatype to accept this in body, when using System.Text.Json? Previously, we have used JArray using JSON.NET.
b) How can I then read this input as an array so that I can then convert into generic JsonObject type?

```
[
  { "prop1" : "value1", "prop2" : "value1"},
  { "prop3" : "value3", "prop4" : "value4"},
  { "propx" : "valuex", "propy" : "value6", "nested": { "other": [1,23,45] }}
]
```

I am also open to option of accepting NDJSON.

Thanks!

Comment: You seem to be answering your own question, as you mention the existence of [JsonArray](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.nodes.jsonarray?view=net-7.0), so could you explain what the problem is with using that?

Comment: if I use [FromBody] JsonArry input, I am not be get pass the validation error in Swagger. I get the below error.

 "Unable to find a constructor to use for type System.Text.Json.Nodes.JsonArray. Path '', line 1, position 1."

Comment: Works for me in .net 6 - see answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all I do is create a new .net Web API from the standard template and add the following action:

> ```
>     [HttpPost]
>     public async Task<IActionResult> Post(JsonArray array)
>     {
>         foreach(var node in array)
>         {
>             Console.WriteLine(node);
>         }
>         return Ok();
>     }
> ```

And pass the content you have specified in the question using the built-in swagger UI:

[image: example of using swagger UI to test the posted example]

And I can step through in the debugger and observe that the request has been deserialized to do what I please with:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Tom. I eventually realized that the issue that I was facing was due to other reason. I was trying this in an existing API that was specifically using Newtonsoft by having AddNewtonsoftJson. So input was going through validation applied by that library. So looks like either I will have to port remaining functionality out to also use System.Text.Json or continue using JArray for this requirement also. I am going to accept this as answer.

Answer (score 0):

From body you can receive `([FromBody]List<object> input)` or `([FromBody]List<dynamic> input)` and access to properties dynamically or serialize to typed objects.